# Pathauto conditions

Tags: 8, path-aliases

Is it possible for Pathauto to have one pattern for a content type, and a different pattern for the same content type based on the value of a field in that content type? I have a checkbox field and if its checked I want to use a different pathauto setting. Right now the only condition Pathauto has is based on content type. Is there a hook that can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. There exists [`hook_pathauto_pattern_alter()`](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/pathauto/tree/pathauto.api.php?h=8.x-1.x) for this purpose. Per the docs:

> Alter the pattern to be used before an alias is generated by Pathauto.
>
> This hook will only be called if a default pattern is configured (on 
>   admin/config/search/path/patterns).

A hook invocation takes arguments in which you can inspect the type and alter `&$pattern` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I found a good example of this hook here: https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/pathauto-less-traveled/